# Wifi Snooping over phone

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, lan, wireless-access-point

I connect to the wifi acccess-point at work, but recently
I suspect that data on my phone is being snooped-out from my phone connected to my office's Wifi network.

[Phone Model: Sony Ericsson Xperia Neo V, Android v2.3; Wifi accespoint: Belkin G]

How can i check my suspicion?
Or What are the ways i could get over them? (obviously i want to stay connected to the wifi n/w)

Any thoughts on these points?

Comment: What activity is leading you to believe you're being snooped?

Comment: If the network is encrypted its very likely your WiFi traffic generated by your phone is being snooped on. Your cellular network traffic is another story. Since your running a vulerable version of Android which isn't even supported, even if you were being snooped your options are limited.

Comment: @WesSayeed I saw some pesonal files on some file servers, mainly handled by our SysAdmin :|

Comment: @Ramhound I am more concerned about the accessibility of files in my device rather than the network traffic.

Comment: @pulsarjune - Android does not allow remote access to the files on the device unless an application is installed.  If you have no said application that offers that feature you have nothing worry about.  There isn't a "backdoor" in Android if thats what your wondering.

Comment: @Ramhound that was exactly what i was asking for. Thanks. I will investigate more on this anyway and update here. Cheers :)

Comment: Solution: Don't connect your phone to the office wireless network.

Comment: @joeqwerty that's obviously not what i want

Answer (score -3):

You'd need a firewall on your phone.  Unfortunately, this is not a built-in feature of Android.  You'd have to download an app for it, and such an app would likely require your phone to be rooted.

Comment: thanks Wes. I'm more into investigating the possibility of file leak, before i move into a firewalled device.

Comment: There's no real way to tell you're being snooped, since by definition snooping is a stealthy activity :-)  You'd need some app that could monitor the activity on your phone. I don't know of any. That's not to say they don't exist though.